# Add Mac (OS X) to Active Directory DNS name resolution

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, mac-osx

I'm running an Active Directory domain via Windows Server 2008; it's running DNS and DHCP, there is only one subnet. All of my Windows computers are able to ping each other my name, but I can't ping any OS X systems.

What do I need to do so that DNS can resolve names for the OS/X systems, allowing me to ping and otherwise address them my network name?

(I admit that I find AD and DNS somewhat incomprehensible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming based on your question that the OS X systems are not joined to the domain? If so it is a likely a permissions issue on your DNS server - only authenticated systems are able to perform DNS updates, therefore their names never make it into DNS.

To adjust so you do not need to join your Macs to the domain or manually make the entries:

Open the DNS console.
Select your DNS server.
Select your domain.
Right click and open the general properties.
Under "Dynamic Updates" choose the option "Nonsecure and Secure".

You also need to be sure your Macs are using the correct DNS suffix. This can come from either your DHCP server or you can set it by hand.

EDIT - as @voretaq7 points out there are security implications for doing this. It is theoretically possible for someone to change the DNS name you use to access a server for example.

For test best security you would want to get your Macs authenticated in your domain. From there this issue should resolve itself.

Comment: There are, as the option implies, ***security implications*** to enabling non-secure dynamic DNS updates…

Comment: What is the effective difference between configuring DHCP to update DNS information (both servers are running DHCP and DNS) vs. configuring the DNS zone to allow nonsecure updates?  Would either technique accomplish the result?  Is one more/less desirable?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use the DNS name of the Macs, then should either consider [binding the Macs to your AD](http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-join-a-mac-os-x-computer-to-active-directory/) or manually add entries for the Macs in your DNS system. It's easy to do either and will make your life easier.

Comment: What are the implications if integration?  Will this make the Mac dependent on AD domain authentication?  If so, how will laptops operate when they don't have access to the domain?  Also, how would this affect existing log-ins?

Comment: @RobertAltman: Yes the Mac's will augment their local accounts with the AD accounts. So you can login with either type of account. If you have logged once on that laptop and then take it offsite, the login credentials will be caches, much like on Windows laptops. Existing user account will continue to exist; however, you could replace those accounts with AD accounts and user your AD roaming profile accounts instead and then manually copy over the account data.